# Migrate GCP Audit Logs to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, audit-logging

As per the documentation, GCP audit logs are kept for only 13 months. What we want is export those logs to a BigQuery dataset for traceability reasons. The issue is that GCP starts exporting the logs starting from the export enabling time and we would like to export/migrate the already available logs also.

Any idea how we can accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but I don't know if it will be the same format, never tested.

1. Start by activating log analytics on your _Required log storage bucket. Go to log storage and update the storage
   [image]
2. After a while (2 - 5 minutes) edit the bucket and add a BigQuery dataset link
   [image]
3. Finally go to BigQuery and query your data. Perform a `INSERT INTO <target table> Select * from <analytics logs table>` (or similar query) to query your logs and insert them in your target table.
   [image]

Again, I never tested that, and the query could require more tuning to fit the destination table, but, like that, you can copy your existing logs in BigQuery.